# Difference between "se brosser les dents" and "se laver les dents"

Tags: verbes, différence

Is there any difference between the two sentences below?

- Il se brosse les dents.
- Il se lave les dents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IL n'y a pas de différence, mais depuis les années 80 les gens  utilisent de plus en plus « se brosser les dents » ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=se+brosser+les+dents%2Cse+laver+les+dents.&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cse%20brosser%20les%20dents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cse%20laver%20les%20dents%20.%3B%2Cc0)).

Cependant, certaines personnes pourraient parler de « laver » lorsque le nettoyage des dents comprend en plus du brossage l'utilisation de fil dentaire. Mais même un organisme concerné de près par les soins dentaires, c'est à dire la Sécurité Sociale, n'insiste pas sur cette différence, comme le montre un de leurs textes prodiguant les conseils habituels en matière d'hygiène dentaire.

> ([réf.](https://www.ameli.fr/assure/sante/bons-gestes/quotidien/brosser-dents)) Il est recommandé de se brosser les dents deux fois par jour, avec un dentifrice fluoré. Pour un lavage efficace, réalisez soigneusement toutes les étapes de brossage. Complétez cette opération en nettoyant les interstices entre les dents avec du fil dentaire.

Comment: C'est idiomatique, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de différence entre "se laver les dents" et "se brosser les dents", quand on prononce cette phrase, on ne se dit pas, ah non, je vais plutôt me laver les dents, plutôt que de me les brosser, parce que je compte utiliser du fil dentaire. Les deux sont synonymes: le brossage est un nettoyage, et le nettoyage peut comprendre plusieurs actions.